# Packing small items into a big box

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm finding a solution to count the number of boxes needed to pack the products of a shopping cart. Each product have its height, width, length. The big box dimension is fixed

```
//big box size
$max_height = 20;
$max_width = 30;
$max_length = 40;

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $height = $product->height;
    $width = $product->width;
    $length = $product->length;
}
```

I knew it is a `3d` bin packing problem, but is there any other easier method to count the number of boxes approximately?

Comment: The simple way would be to use the volume and simply add the volume of all products, divide it by the volume of the big box and round the result up. You may wanna try this with a few examples to see how accurate the approximation is going to be on average.

Comment: What about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170478/how-to-create-an-optimized-packing-function-in-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ingo's solution in the comments of the original question is a good one, here's an implementation of it.

```
//big box size
$max_height = 20;
$max_width = 30;
$max_length = 40;
$max_volume = $max_height * $max_width * $max_length;

$tot_height = 0;
$tot_width = 0;
$tot_length = 0;

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $tot_height += $product->height;
    $tot_width += $product->width;
    $tot_length += $product->length;
}

$tot_volume = $tot_height * $tot_width * $tot_length;

$boxes_needed = ceil($tot_volume / $max_volume);
```

If you're actually going to be using this in the real world then maybe add an extra box as it's unlikely everything will fit together to fill a boxes volume perfectly, unless you're a grandmaster of tetris :)

Comment: Adding one box more to every order may be a bit overkill, though. Maybe a more subtle way would be using a factor `p` that is slightly greater than 1 and using it on `$tot_volume` (in your code). The best value for `p` could be adjusted after looking at examples or over time. That is if one wants to invest the time to do so.